# Redirecting all pages from site A to site B, including http & https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I’ve recently migrated everything from an old website to a new website, and I’m trying to make redirects so that typing https://www.oldsite.com (and other variations like http://www.oldsite.com, https://oldsite.com and http://oldsite.com) automatically go to https://www.newsite.com.

I’ve successfully made a .htaccess file that does everything I need (including http://www.oldsite.com redirecting to https://www.newsite.com), but the only part I cannot do is make https://www.oldsite.com or any subpages (https://www.oldsite.com/*) redirect to the equivalent page on the new site (the page structures on both sites are identical, just different domain names).

I’ve had to log into GoDaddy and create manual redirects for the important pages (which automatically generated most of the code), hence why the code I’m going to show seems long. Also, the way my 2 domains are set up is that the old site is now an ‘add-on domain’ of the new site, meaning there’s a folder in the main site that contains the new site, each with separate htaccess files.

How can I fix these redirects? I’ve tried a lot of tweaks which haven’t got everything working.

Here’s the .htaccess code for the new site (parent directory of the old site - it might be only the ***first 5 lines*** or so that do it as most of the code is just each manual redirect automatically generated from GoDaddy):

```
RewriteOptions inherit

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.newsite.com/other/404-error.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?oldsite\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^hosting$ "http\:\/\/www\.dpbolvw\.net\/click\-8487961\-11003096" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^checker$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/tools\/domain\-name\-checker\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ecommerce$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ecommerce\-store\-woocommerce\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebay\/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/free\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebaypro$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/pro\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^other\/ebay\-template\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/free\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebaycheats$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebaycheat$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emprovider$ "https\:\/\/www\.getresponse\.com\/\?a\=oldsite" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emailprovider$ "https\:\/\/www\.getresponse\.com\/\?a\=oldsite" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^em$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^email$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emails$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emcheat$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emcheats$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emailcheat$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emailcheats$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^photography$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/resources\.html\#photography\-tools" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^photography\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/resources\.html\#photography\-tools" [R=301,L]
```

And here’s the .htaccess code for the old site (again, maybe just the ***first 5 lines*** or so):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^hosting$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/hosting" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^checker$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/tools\/domain\-name\-checker\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ecommerce$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ecommerce\-store\-woocommerce\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebay\/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/free\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebaypro$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/pro\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^other\/ebay\-template\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/free\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebaycheats$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebaycheat$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emprovider$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/emprovider" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emailprovider$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/emailprovider" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^em$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^email$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emails$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emcheat$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emcheats$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emailcheat$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^emailcheats$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/email\-marketing\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^photography$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/resources\.html\#photography\-tools" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^photography\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/resources\.html\#photography\-tools" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebay\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebay\/pro\-template\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/pro\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebay\/free\-template\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/free\-template\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ebay\/cheat\-sheet\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ebay\/cheat\-sheet\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^resources\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/resources\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ecommerce\-store\-woocommerce\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/ecommerce\-store\-woocommerce\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^other\/new\-subscriber\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/other\/new\-subscriber\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^other\/welcome\-back\.html$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/other\/welcome\-back\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated here as I’m baffled, thank you.

Note: I think the parent .htaccess file affects the child .htaccess file.

Also: a better way of explaining this would be I just want any url variation of oldsite.com to go to the same variation of newsite.com (e.g. https://www.oldsite.com/somepage.html would redirect to https://www.newsite.com/somepage.html, so only oldsite is replaced with newsite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On` line**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Also as a side note you can replace **everywhere** these 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
```

With this single conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: thanks but this did not work. I tried adding this below the RewriteEngine On line:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

Comment: which .htaccess file were you referring to? I presumed the old site htaccess file (in the child directory of the new site), but I tried on both separately and neither worked

Comment: DO you have more than one .htaccess on old site? If not then it should be placed in site root .htaccess of old site. Also tell which URL is not working for you after adding this rule as I suggested.

Comment: There's only one .htaccess file on the old site (and one on the new parent site). Any URL that has the https prefix to the old site doesn't work (as it shows the SSL error 'connection is not private' message) but http prefix is still fine. For example, https:// www.oldsite.com/ has a SSL error, whereas http:// www.oldsite.com/ has no error and redirects correctly to the new site. Thanks for your help

Comment: `SSL error 'connection is not private' message)` cannot be fixed by redirect rules because **SSL handshake between browser and web server happens before redirect module is loaded** and this is due to security reasons. SSL warning can only be fixed by placing right SSL certs on both sites.